# Where is the one to one correlation between the assembly and cpp code?

Tags: c++, assembly

I tried to examine how the this code will be in assembly:

```
int main(){
  if (0){
    int x = 2;
    x++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I was wondering what does `if (0)` mean?

I used the shell command `g++ -S helloWorld.cpp` in `Linux`

and got this code:

```
    .file   "helloWorld.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

1. I expected that the assembly will contain some `JZ` but where is it?
2. How can I compile the code without optimization?

Comment: compile also this `int main(){return 0;}` for comparison.

Comment: How can I compile the code without optimization?

Comment: That's not even an optimization. Including a code that's in a `if(0)` scope would be contrary to what that code should do - which is precisely *nothing*.

Comment: Your assumption that there is (or should be) a one to one correlation between asm und c++ is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct, guaranteed relationship between C++ source code and
the generated assembler.  The C++ source code defines a certain
semantics, and the compiler outputs machine code which will implement
the observable behavior of those semantics.  How the compiler does this,
and the actual code it outputs, can vary enormously, even over the same
underlying hardware; I would be very disappointed in a compiler which
generated code which compared `0` with `0`, and then did a conditional
jump if the results were equal, regardless of what the C++ source code
was.

In your example, the only observable behavior in your code is to return
`0` to the OS.  Anything the compiler generates must do this (and have
no other observable behavior).  The code you show isn't optimal for 
this:

```
xorl %eax, %eax
ret
```

is really all that is needed.  But of course, the compiler is free to
generate a lot more if it wants.  (Your code, for example, sets up a
frame to support local variables, even though there aren't any.  Many
compilers do this systematically, because most debuggers expect it, and
get confused if there is no frame.)

With regards to optimization, this depends on the compiler.  With g++,
`-O0` (that's the letter O followed by the number zero) turns off all
optimization.  This is the default, however, so it is effectively what
you are seeing.  In addition to having several different levels of
optimization, g++ supports turning individual optimizations off or on.
You might want to look at the complete list:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler eliminates that code as dead code, e.g. code that will never run. What you're left with is establishing the stack frame and setting the return value of the function. `if(0)` is never true, after all. If you want to get `JZ`, then you should probably do something like `if(variable == 0)`. Keep in mind that the compiler is in no way required to actually emit the `JZ` instruction, it may use any other means to achieve the same thing. Compiling a high level language to assembly is very rarely a clear, one-to-one correlation.

Comment: And `variable` better be defined as `volatile int variable`, or the compiler will notice that there's no point in reading it.

Answer (score 1):

The code has probably been optimized.

```
if (0){
   int x = 2;
  x++;
}
```

has been eliminated.

`movl    $0, %eax` is where the return value been set. It seems the other instructions are just program init and exit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the compiler optimized it away, since it's never true.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer removed the if conditional and all of the code inside, so it doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

the if (0) {} block has been optimized out by the compiler, as this will never be called.
so your function do only return 0 (movl $0, %eax)